# Filtering using filter,streams and for each in a single line

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

geocode body is a class containing location as an entity which is again a class containing addressclass  and address contains latitude and longitude. how to fetch latitude and longitude for each loaction and adding it to the stops

```
List<Location> geoList = geocodeBody.getLocations().stream()
           .filter(s-> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lon=s.getAddress().getLon()) && 
                StringUtils.isNotEmpty(lat=s.getAddress().getLat()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
//Need to add latitude and logitude for each stops
geoList.forEach((Stops)->{
     Stops.add(lat); // adding latitude
     Stops.add(lon); // adding longitude
});
```

Comment: Please format your code first. What do you want to solve? Pleasecheck this out provide us with a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example How does this geo class and others look like?

Comment: @Ravindra Ranwala I am getting syntax error for using streams,filter and foreach in a single operation

Comment: What is your entity structure for those involved in the question? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How is this even a correct syntax `lon=s.getAddress().getLon()` inside a method call?

Comment: @Naman geocode body is a class containing location as an entity which is again a class containing addressclass  and address contains latitude and longitude. how to fetch latitude and longitude for each loaction and adding it to the stops

Comment: Why not similar to `s.getAddress().getLon()` such that your code would look like : `geoList.forEach((loc)->{
     stops.add(loc.getAddress().getLat()); // adding latitude
     stops.add(loc.getAddress().getLon()); // adding longitude
});` ?

Comment: @Prashant Iknow it shouldn't be but i am finding a way to add those values into lat and lon. Could it be achieved using streams fileter and foreach loop?

Comment: You are iterating over *multiple* locations, but want to store all their lon & lat values in a *single* variable? How is that supposed to work? Then, you are iterating over the collected locations, to add the very values you just received from the same locations? What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do filtering then you can add lat and lon in the way you want:

```java
geocodeBody.getLocations().stream()
.filter(location -> 
    location.getAddress() != null 
    && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(location.getAddress().getLon())
    && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(location.getAddress().getLat())
).forEach(location -> {
      Stops.add(location.getAddress().getLat()); // adding latitude
      Stops.add(location.getAddress().getLon()); // adding longitude
    });
```